# Wronskian: How to prove that $W'(t)=\text{tr}(A) W(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this system of differential equations:
$$
X'(t)= A(t) X(t),
$$

where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of continuous functions.

We know that if $\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\}$ is a system of solutions, then the Wronskian is  $$W(t)=\det( X_1(t),\ldots,X_n(t)).$$ 
How do we prove that $$W'(t)=\text{tr}(A)\, W(t)?$$

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214908/proof-for-the-derivative-of-the-determinant-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 2):

$\det$ is n-linear so, in a basis ${\mathcal{B}}$.

$W'(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\det_{\mathcal{B}}(X_1(t),...,X'_j(t),...X_n(t))$

$W'(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\det_{\mathcal{B}}(X_1(t),...,A(t)X_j(t),...X_n(t))$

Lemma:

$\psi:   E^n \ni (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{n}\det_{\mathcal{B}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{j-1},u(x_j),x_{j+1},\ldots,x_n)$ is a n-linear form which is antisymmetric (if you permut two variables then the result is multiplied by $-1$) hence it is proportional to $\det$.

It is not difficult to show the scalar is $tr(u)$ (i.e. $\psi(\mathcal{B}) = tr(u))$.

Comment: how you write $W'(t)$ like this ?

Comment: what is $B$ here ?

Comment: i really don't understand how you do

Comment: i don't know yhis, bur i need to have this in system of differential equation

Comment: Can you delete your answer, i want to delete my question and ask one in linear algebra , thank you

Comment: but your answer disn't help me , it is not clear